# SQL - Select One less record from total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Following is the data and I want to output having one less record of each value.

for e.g There are

Total A are 4,so output shall have 3 A

Total B is 1, so output should not have any B

Total C are 2,so output should have One C

Total D is 1, so output should not have any D

Total F is 3, so output should have 2 F

```
+------+
| Data |
+------+
| A    |
| A    |
| A    |
| A    |
| B    |
| C    |
| C    |
| D    |
| E    |
| F    |
| F    |
| F    |
+------+
```

**Output**

```
+------+
| Data |
+------+
| A    |
| A    |
| A    |
| C    |
| F    |
| F    |
+------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`; it is far better if you have an ordering column (I assumed `id`):

```
select data
from (select data, row_number() over(partition by data order by id) rn from mytable) t
where rn > 1
```

If you don't have an ordering column, then you can just `order by data`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.data
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by data order by data) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Data, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Data) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Data ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Data
FROM cte
WHERE rn < cnt;
```

In plain English terms, the above approach retains any record whose row number (based on some arbitrary ordering) is *less* than the total number of records in each `Data` group.  This means that one record per group would be excluded in the result set.